# Global payments - sandbox url transactions log

Tags: realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

When implementing a payment integration using Global payments HPP, can the payments performed through the sandbox url (https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay) be checked for accuracy on some dashboard similar to what is found on the merchant portal for the production url?

I am looking for testing alternatives but can't find the registry of all payments performed through the sandbox url. Does it not exist? If so, what alternatives are there for testing the payment results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that might have the same question, the answer is `https://realcontrol.sandbox.realexpayments.com/#/login`

Comment: Through that url and after authentication you'll find a dashboard with all the transactions made by your account through the sandbox url. Offers a way of visually checking the sandbox transaction results which is what I was looking for. The url is the sandbox merchant portal.

Comment: dont know if you can recall this now. But is it possible to query a successful transaction by an order_id or something? via an API of global payments?

Comment: See how to in this docs page: https://developer.globalpay.com/api/transactions#/Get%20a%20Transaction/getSingleSaleOrRefundTransaction